# ALT key suddenly stops working - have to resort to ALT + CTRL

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Operating System is Windows 10, Keyboard Layout is German, Language English.

Essentially, every now and then the ALT key decides to no longer allow me to use the "shortcuts" - say, on a german keyboard, "ALT + E" for the € sign. My keyboard layout hasn't changed (it's still the german layout, english language), but switching between any of the available options of keyboard / language settings doesn't seem to change anything.

I can still *USE* the ALT key for other things like alt-codes or alt-tabbing, but I can't type any of the special characters without also using CTRL which is infuriating when it happens for seemingly "no reason".

A common problems seems to be virtual machines - for most occurances however, I haven't even launched the related application (and it doesn't auto-boot with the system either), so I doubt that would be it.

I have found many issues about the ALT keys suddenly no longer working, but none of them appear to be about or solve this particular problem. (It's also very difficult to search for considering there's so many variations on similar problems)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/365XO.png)

Comment: You probably have inadvertently switched keyboards, and the key that you're having the problem with is the RIGHT Alt key, which on most non-US keyboard layouts (and on the US-International layout) is mapped to AltGr, which is mimicked by CTRL-ALT. Check the keyboard layout indicator in the lower right, on the task bar.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply, but it does say that it uses the german keyboard layout - CTRL + ALT is still the only thing that works. Adding a screenshot above.

Comment: Are you having problems with one alt key, or both? Every time I've had a problem that seems to be what you're describing, it's because the keyboard layout has switched - on Windows 10, it seems to be maintained on a per-application basis, rather than being "global".

Comment: Exactly the same setup - exactly the same issue. Reboot works for me, but after working for half a day, the problem is back.